# Execute different lambdas based on input

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I need SWF workflow to trigger one of three lambda functions. SWF workflow should accept some input and determine and trigger the appropriate lambda. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AWS Flow Framework then it is going to look something like:

```
@Execute
public void myWorkflow(Whatever input) {
   if (match1(input)) {
      lambdaClient.schedleLambdaFunction(name1, input1);
   } else if (match2(input)) {
      lambdaClient.schedleLambdaFunction(name2, input2);
   } else if (match3(input)) {
      lambdaClient.schedleLambdaFunction(name3, input3);
   }
}
```

For more info see [AWS Flow Framework for Java Programming Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/features.html),
[AWS Flow Framework samples for Amazon SWF](https://aws.amazon.com/code/Amazon-SWF/3015904745387737) and [AWS Flow Framework Recipes](https://aws.amazon.com/code/2535278400103493).

Comment: Thank you Maxim. I just wanted to confirm that here do I need to create activity worker or directly I should create workflow worker and trigger the same ?

Comment: Also Please suggest if this is the right approach to use workflow just to trigger lambda functions ?

Comment: Sure, if all your activities can be implemented as lambda functions, then it is right approach.

Comment: With the above code when I am starting my workflow it is always timed out and lambda is not triggering. I checked cloudwatch log for my lambda and no execution for my lambda. :(

Comment: Check the execution history at the AWS SWF Console. Does it contain lamda related events? What these events are saying?

Comment: Hey Maxim, I am not bale to see any lambda related events in execution history. It is giving Jackson parser error.

Comment: Always getting this error :( ["com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.DataConverterException",{"cause":["com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException",

Comment: Look at the stack trace. It should contain more info about the exception. My guess is that parameters passed to the workflow cannot be deserialized.

Comment: Thank You Maxim. It was the issue with the parameter what I was passing.Now it is working as expected.

Answer (score -1):

You can build a stream by parts as long as you add only intermediate operations. Only when you use terminal operations the stream is actually being executed. See for example [Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams, Part 1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html), section "Stream Operations: Exploiting Streams to Process Data":

> Stream operations that can be connected are called intermediate operations. They can be connected together because their return type is a Stream. Operations that close a stream pipeline are called terminal operations. They produce a result from a pipeline such as a List, an Integer, or even void (any non-Stream type).
>
> You might be wondering why the distinction is important. Well, intermediate operations do not perform any processing until a terminal operation is invoked on the stream pipeline; they are “lazy.” This is because intermediate operations can usually be “merged” and processed into a single pass by the terminal operation.